# Check if a Point is between two Points

Tags: java, math, point, dot-product

I just recognized my math is a bit rusty.. I wanna check if `Point C is between Point A and Point B`. C can be on the line segment of A and B, or not. There can be three cases and I have to identify all of them:

- C is between A and B

  ```
     C  
    / \  
   A---B
  ```
- C is in front of A and B

  ```
  C  
   \  \
    A--B
  ```
- C is in the back of A and B

  ```
         C  
     /  /
    A--B
  ```

The "sketch" in the last two points should be a triangle.

I used the dotproduct to check if C is between A and B.

```
if (VectorOf(AB) * VectorOf(BC)) >= 0)
```

To check if C is in the back of A and B i use this:

```
if (VectorOf(AB) * VectorOf(BC)) < 0)
```

But how to identify if C is in front of A and B?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Just use the dot product starting from point B.

```
if (VectorOf(AC) * VectorOf(AB) < 0) {
    // C is on the left of A
}
else {
    if (VectorOf(BC) * VectorOf(BA) < 0) {
        // C is on the right of B
    }
    else {
        // C is between A and B
    }
}
```

Alternatively, you can compute the projected distance, relative to vector AB :

```
(VectorOf(AC) * VectorOf(AB)) / (VectorOf(AB) * VectorOf(AB))
```

The result would be < 0, between 0 and 1, or > 1 in your three cases, as shows the math below :

```
      C
     /│
    / │
   /  │
──A── H ─────B─────
```

The definition of the dot product is that

**AC** · **AB** = AC×AB×cos(Â) = AH×AB (signed : negative if C is left of A, positive if C is to the right).

**AB** · **AB** = AB² (positive)

The result of the division is the signed ratio AH/AB :

```
-   0          1   >1
────A── H ─────B─────
```

Answer (score 0):

How about using coordinates:

```
Between: a.x > c.x > b.x || a.x < c.x < b.x
Front: c.x < a.x && b.x
Back: c.x > b.x && a.x
```

Answer (score 0):

I'm assuming that A,B don't necessarily have the same Y coordinate, even though this is what the diagrams would suggest. You would want to use [vector projection](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Vector_projection).

let `b = B - A`, `c = C - A`, then the projection is: `u = dot(b,c) / |b|`,

Front: `u < 0`; Between: `0 <= u <= |b|`; Back: `|b| < u`.

or: `u = dot(b,c) / dot(b,b)`,

Front: `u < 0`; Between: `0 <= u <= 1`; Back: `1 < u`

Answer (score 0):

It seems that with your definitions the point C is "between" A and B if angles CAB and ABC are both acute, front of A-B is angle CAB is obtuse, and behind of A-B if angle ABC is obtuse.

You can use the dot product to find if an angle is acute or obtuse: if XYZ is acute the doc product of XY·YZ is negative, and if it's obtuse the dot product is positive.