# How to find a current position is between the two Latitude and Longitude?

Tags: android, sqlite, google-maps, geolocation

I have a `SQLite` database which stores `latitude` and `longitude`. I have to find if the users current location is between the `Latitude` and `Longitude`(Which is stored in Database) or not.

I been looking for a while to find a solution for this problem but couldn't get it. Most of them are related with the distance calculation.

How to find the current location(obtained in the app) is between the `Latitude` and `Longitude`(Which is stored in SQLite Database)?

Comment: It's not clear what you are asking. Do you have lower and upper bound for latitude and lower and upper bound for longitude?

Comment: @Grzegorz edited the question. I didn't have any lower and upper bound.

Comment: You have some locations and want to know between which ones your current location is?

Comment: @SteveBenett Yes it is...

Answer (score 1):

I am not sure if you exactly want but what i think

what you have : two geographical point (two pair of attitude and longitude )

what you want : calculate the adjoining regions covered between the two geo points , and check if the user is within that are

for that what you can do is :

1 : suppose the two points are diameteric terminals of a circle and search if the user is within this circle , like this Image

[image]

this approach might make you search a little irrelavant region

2 : suppose the two point are two ends of a straight line , consider a distance , say 50 km , on both sides , and search the 100 km wide strip from point A to point B
like this Image

[image]

Answer (score 1):

Assume you have two locations a and b and your current location c.

```
   C  
  / \  
 A---B
```

You can use the [dotproduct](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Dot_product) to calculate if c is between a and b:

If the dotproduct of two vectors is >0, the degrees between these vectors is <90°.

Know you need two calculations like this:

```
if(Vector(AB) * Vector(AC) > 0 && Vector(BC) * Vector(BA) > 0)
    // your location is between
```

You can also look [here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/18171840/check-if-a-point-is-between-two-points) and [here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/328107/how-can-you-determine-a-point-is-between-two-other-points-on-a-line-segment) for more details.